# How to loop on the if statement if it is a WebElement?

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to manipulate this blocks of codes:

```
List<WebElement> more = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/button"));
        if(more.size()!=0){
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/button")).click();
        }else {
            WebElement present = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody"));
            List<WebElement> list = present.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr"));
            System.out.println("Total Number of TR: " + list.size());
        }
```

What Im trying to do hopefully is that before I execute what is in the IF statement I want to loop that everytime it sees the element ***/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/button*** it will be click and if it is not available then ill execute this:

```
WebElement present = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody"));
            List<WebElement> list = present.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr"));
            System.out.println("Total Number of TR: " + list.size());
```

For further info what I am trying to do here is this.
I am on a listview for a specific module, and then at the button there is a "Click here for more records" -> its XPath is `/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/button`
I want that if i am in the listview and that button is present as mentioned above -I want to click it. And if in the listview there is no button "Click here for more records" (for example the records is composed of 5records only so there is no pagination clearly) I want to execute a blocks of code.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, which is why I haven't written this as an answer.  But maybe you could write `if(more.size()==0){` followed by the code that you currently have in the `else` block.  Then have a `for` loop, something like `for(WebElement element : more){ element.click(); }`.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: What I am trying to achieve here is that :
Whenever this element is present - **bold**/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/button**bold** I would like to click on it and if there is no such element I would like to perform this statements:

Comment: this :


WebElement present = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody"));
    List<WebElement> list = present.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr"));
    System.out.println("Total Number of TR: " + list.size());

Comment: So you're not trying to trap the case where there are several such elements?  OK I certainly misunderstood.  Where does the loop come in then?

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your query is that you want to loop your IF condition statement multiple times until your else condition satisfies. For this, you can try following code:

```
     (1) try{
      (2)    String xpathVAL="/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/button";
         (3) int i=1;
       (4)   while(i!=0){

              (5)   if(driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathVAL)).size() != 0)

             (6)    {
                (7)      driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathVAL).click();
                (8)   Thread.sleep(2000);

               (9)  }

             (10)    else{
              (11)              Thread.sleep(2000);
              (12)         WebElement present = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody"));
    (13)    List<WebElement> list = present.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr"));
     (14)   LOGGER.debug("Total Number of TR: " + list.size());
        (15) i=0;
        (16)         }
      (17)    }
    (18)      }catch(Exception e){
        (19)  LOGGER.debug("Exception Caught");
(20) WebElement present = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody"));
       List<WebElement> list = present.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/table/tbody/tr"));

          }
```

I think your requirement would be to keep click a button until some window appears and the button disappears. What I suggest for this is, apply "Thread.sleep(//some 3-4 seconds//)". However, it is poor style of coding and using forceful thread is not suggested by many standards. You can put some other **implicit wait** there. Also, if your element is not found after certain period of time, you can apply break condition after certain time interval, else it will go to infinite loop. If you are having trouble writing the code, let me know and I will help you in that.

**EDIT**

Try following points to remove element not present in cache:-

1. Use Explicit wait(Thread.sleep) at line 8 and line 11
2. Change your xpath from position based to some id/name/class type. Changing it to **NAME** based gets more clearer picture of the element even if its position is changed.
3. Again re-initialize the element if exception is caught at line 20.

Comment: I am on travel, and haven't actually tested the code. Sorry if some bug appears.

Comment: Happy to help, please accept the answer if it met your requirement :)

Comment: HI @aditya . im still having this error :(

 Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up

Comment: It's so funny that I am coming after 6+ years on this post and happy to see the young me was better in technical stuff than what I am right now. Btw hope you figured something out for your query Jean